# Apache mod rewrite change all urls to lowercase with htaccess only

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are currently on shared hosting and don't have access to apache global/vhost config so we are forced to work with .htaccess As viable solution we used following rules but in certain cases they lead to

```
RewriteRule '^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$' and URI '/something/tYSt/' exceeded maximum length (16380)
```

Any hints how to overcome this?

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
  Options -Indexes
  Options +FollowSymLinks

  RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
  RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
  RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
  RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
  RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
  RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
  RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
  RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
  RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
  RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
  RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
  RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
  RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
  RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
  RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
  RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
  RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
  RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
  RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
  RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
  RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
  RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
  RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
  RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
  RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
  RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2
  RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: All urls with capital letters and more than one slash. As example says - domain.com/something/Test will trigger an error. Error occur also with domain.com/something/second/Third. If we are working with domain.com/Test all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution for you. Just put this in a `.htaccess` in your Document Root `/` directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)A(.*)$ $1a$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)B(.*)$ $1b$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)C(.*)$ $1c$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)D(.*)$ $1d$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)E(.*)$ $1e$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)F(.*)$ $1f$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)G(.*)$ $1g$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)H(.*)$ $1h$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)I(.*)$ $1i$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)J(.*)$ $1j$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)K(.*)$ $1k$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)L(.*)$ $1l$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)M(.*)$ $1m$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)N(.*)$ $1n$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)O(.*)$ $1o$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)P(.*)$ $1p$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)R(.*)$ $1r$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)S(.*)$ $1s$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)T(.*)$ $1t$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)U(.*)$ $1u$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)V(.*)$ $1v$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)W(.*)$ $1w$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)X(.*)$ $1x$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

The main reason with your version is that you append the original URI with any rewrite and so you end up with `/something/tyst/something/tySt/something/tYSt/something/tYSt/....` and this is why you exceeded maximum length.

*I tested this positive with Apache 2.4.27*

#### Notice

Delete your browser cache before you test this.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking a look at this - I tested the mentioned code but unfortunately it seems that it simply rewrite all requests to the base url. All links lead to the homepage, I can confirm this on localhost and on the shared host with apache 2.4

Comment: Do you have any other rewrite in place? My code can not be the reason for it!

Comment: I cleaned almost everything from .htaccess for the test. I think `Options +FollowSymLinks` is the cause for this because when I remove it, it works, but the clean urls are not in place so I get not found error.

Comment: I edited the question with full htacces content, however I tried now simply to add the L flag on all 28 rows for each letter and locally it is working perfectly. However if I use your code I still keep getting redirected, is it possible to be due apache config? I have doubts that shared hosting has some type of caching except the normal one as changes are reflected with 15 minutes delay after each upload.

Comment: Delete your browser cache before you test this.

Comment: I assume you want rewrite all to `index.php` at the end, so I added the last 3 lines as well. If not just delete it and this `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` is actually obsolete.

Comment: Once again thank you very much for your efforts - I have tested the code but it just seems that again it redirects only to the homepage and thats it. Maybe this issue is caused by shared hosting apache settings, problematic section is `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]` I have tested on localhost and there it seems to be working, I think without proper access to apache config this is impossible to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've used multiple sources including this one, and i got a running .htaccess which redirects uppercase letters to lowercase letters without looping forever.

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)A(.*)$ $1a$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)B(.*)$ $1b$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)C(.*)$ $1c$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)D(.*)$ $1d$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)E(.*)$ $1e$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)F(.*)$ $1f$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)G(.*)$ $1g$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)H(.*)$ $1h$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)I(.*)$ $1i$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)J(.*)$ $1j$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)K(.*)$ $1k$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)L(.*)$ $1l$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)M(.*)$ $1m$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)N(.*)$ $1n$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)O(.*)$ $1o$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)P(.*)$ $1p$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)R(.*)$ $1r$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)S(.*)$ $1s$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)T(.*)$ $1t$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)U(.*)$ $1u$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)V(.*)$ $1v$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)W(.*)$ $1w$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)X(.*)$ $1x$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2 [L]
# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This did nothing in my case